# I can't copy a list in python

Tags: python, list, copy

I'm trying to create a copy of a list and use it inside my function.

```
import copy
islands=[['a','b','c',],[]]
def transfer(thing):
    new_islands=copy.copy(islands)
    new_islands[0].remove(thing)
    return new_islands
transfer('b')
print(islands)
//output ['a','c']
```

I have tried other methods of copying such as `new_list=old_list[:]` and even creating a for loop that appends every element to an empty list, but I still can't get to separate both lists.

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I really couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Comment: use `deepcopy()` to also copy the data of the inner lists.

Comment: Solved my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the inner list as well:

```
islands = [['a','b','c',],[]]

def transfer(thing):  
    new_islands = [islands[0].copy(), islands[1].copy()]
    new_islands[0].remove(thing)
    return new_islands

print(transfer('b'), islands)  # [['a', 'c'], []] [['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
```

You can also use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy everything inside the list:

```
from copy import deepcopy

islands = [['a','b','c',],[]]
def transfer(thing):
    new_islands = deepcopy(islands)
    new_islands[0].remove(thing)
    return new_islands
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's try to make it simpler and avoid copy at all:

```
islands=[['a','b','c',],[]]
def transfer(islands, thing):
    return islands[0].remove(thing)

transfer(islands, 'b')
print(islands)
//output ['a','c']
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same behavior ask by the OP. But avoiding the copy is a better way to achieve this!